# How to Properly Short-Circuit Middleware in Django?

Tags: python, django, api, middleware, technical-debt

**CONTEXT:**

I am working on a Django 1.10/Python2.7 app with legacy stuff, and I am preparing part of it to pay some tech debt in near future. For that I need to put some logic on the chain of middleware used in the app to by-pass a whole set of layers underneath the Django ones if the URL being requested is to hit the API new app (`/api` routes).

My idea was to introduce a new middleware in between the Django ones and the custom ones of the project (commented as "Custom middlewares" below as an example of what the proj has - in total about 8 middlewares, some of which make dozens of calls to DB and I don't know yet the implications of removing them or turning them into decorators for requests/views that need them).

That intermediary middleware would short-circuit all the ones below it on `MIDDLEWARE` if the url starts with `/api`.

I tried short-circuiting the Middleware chain in Django as they say in documentation but it is not working for me.

**HOW I GOT IT WORKING (but not ideal):**

The way I got it working was by doing this (which is not what they say in the documentation):

This is the pre-existing `MIDDLEWARE` chain in `settings.py` in project:

```py
(...)
MIDDLEWARE = (
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',

    'app2.middleware.PreExisting1Middleware',                   # Custom middlewares
    'app3.middleware.PreExisting2Middleware',                   # Custom middlewares
)
(...)
```

I added new `settings.py` key with:

```py
SHORTCIRCUIT_MIDDLWARES_IF_URL_PATTERNS_IN = (r'^/api', )
```

To avoid applying `PreExisting1Middleware`, `PreExisting2Middleware` for URL routes starting with `/api` I created a base Middleware class as such:

```py
import re

from django.conf import settings
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin


class ShortCircuitMiddlewareMixin(MiddlewareMixin):
    def __call__(self, request):
        # Code to be executed for each request before the view (and later middleware) are called.
        response = None
        if hasattr(self, 'process_request') and self.should_middleware_be_applied(request):
            response = self.process_request(request)
        if not response:
            response = self.get_response(request)
        if hasattr(self, 'process_response') and self.should_middleware_be_applied(request):
            response = self.process_response(request, response)
        return response

    def should_middleware_be_applied(self, request):
        short_patterns = getattr(settings, 'SHORTCIRCUIT_MIDDLWARES_IF_URL_PATTERNS_IN', [])
        if hasattr(short_patterns, '__iter__'):
            if any(re.match(pattern, request.path) for pattern in short_patterns):
                print('\nShort-circuiting the middleware: {}'.format(self.__class__.__name__))
                return False
        else:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured(
                "SHORTCIRCUIT_MIDDLWARES_IF_URL_PATTERNS_IN must be an iterable, got '{}'".format(short_patterns))
        return True
```

Then I use it as a base class for the middlewares `PreExisting1Middleware` and `PreExisting2Middleware`, that way, they get short-circuited if said url condition holds true.

```py
Class PreExisting1Middleware(ShortCircuitMiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):
        print('\nprocessing...')
        (...)

Class PreExisting2Middleware(ShortCircuitMiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):
        (...)
```

This works just fine, and I get a nice message on shell saying which middlewares were by-passed that can/should be logged if needed as well.

Now, on to the question....

**MY QUESTION:**

Any idea on how to do it by using the right logic in the `__call__` method below and the MIDDLEWARE config below?

```py
class ConditionallyShortcircuitChainMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Code to be executed for each request before
        # the view (and later middleware) are called.

        response = self.get_response(request)

        # Code to be executed for each request/response after
        # the view is called.

        return response
```

```py
(...)
MIDDLEWARE = (
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',

    'app1.middleware.ConditionallyShortcircuitChainMiddleware', # My new middleware
    'app2.middleware.PreExisting1Middleware',                   # Custom
    'app3.middleware.PreExisting2Middleware',                   # Custom
)
(...)
```

Relevant info from docs:
See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/middleware/#middleware-order-and-layering)

> **Middleware order and layering**
>
> During the request phase, before calling the view, Django applies
>   middleware in the order it’s defined in MIDDLEWARE, top-down.
>
> You can think of it like an onion: each middleware class is a “layer”
>   that wraps the view, which is in the core of the onion. If the request
>   passes through all the layers of the onion (each one calls
>   get_response to pass the request in to the next layer), all the way to
>   the view at the core, the response will then pass through every layer
>   (in reverse order) on the way back out.
>
> If one of the layers decides to short-circuit and return a response
>   without ever calling its get_response, none of the layers of the onion
>   inside that layer (including the view) will see the request or the
>   response. The response will only return through the same layers that
>   the request passed in through.

Comment: What do you mean by "right logic"?

Comment: Hi @schillingt : I mean, what is the logic I have to put on the `def __call__(self, request):` of the middleware that will short-circuit all underneath middleware classes registered in MIDDLEWARE. So, the 'right logic' means what is the code that makes it skip all process_request and process_response and process_exception of the underneath middleware, but still invoke the proper request/response cycle from the views.py up to that middleware.I know that if I do `return self.get_response(request)` it still calls the process_request of the underneath middleware.That shouldn't happen, but it does.

Comment: Clarifying better, I want to return a response on the `def __call__(self, request):` that will short-circuit all underneath middleware. But that response needs to be the result of what comes returned from the views.py for that url. Does that make sense?

Comment: "So, the 'right logic' means what is the code that makes it skip all process_request and process_response and process_exception of the underneath middleware, but still invoke the proper request/response cycle from the views.py" Django doesn't support that, what you have in your question is likely as good as it'll get for you.

Comment: @schillingt got it! Thanks for the help. Guess I'll stick to my code then. Cheers.